# Avoid clipping of an adorner inside a ListBoxItem if its size is greater than the ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, listboxitem

I'm showing various objects inside a ListBox.
Each object have adorners that can be shown in particular cases.

If an adorner is shown, it should be visible even if the size of the ListBoxItem holding my object is less than the size of the adorner; unfortunately at the moment the adorner hides behind the ListBoxItem if it gets too small.

How can i force the adorner to be always on top of the z-order or alternatively how can i avoid to be clipped to the bounds of the ListBoxItem?

Comment: It hides *behind* the `ListBoxItem` if the adorner grows too large, or it gets clipped by the containing `ListBox`?  I would expect the latter, since your adorners are probably being hosted in the `AdornerLayer` owned by the list's `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel it gets clipped by the listboxitem.

Comment: Are you placing an `AdornerDecorator` inside your list item content or item template?  If so, try removing it so the adorners show on the layer owned by the scroll viewer.

Comment: @MikeStrobel it works! Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I added my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect your adorners to be clipped by the `ListBox`, not the `ListBoxItem`.  It sounds like you may be adding an `AdornerDecorator` to your item content or item template.  If that's the case, try removing it and letting the adorners be shown in the layer owned by the list box's `ScrollViewer`.  That should remove the clipping at the item bounds but still clip adorners that extend beyond the viewport.